# JSON deserialization with GSON doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, generics, gson

I'm currently writing an Android app which uses Google's GSON library for JSON deserialization. I already solved this (or at least a *very* similar) problem a while ago, but my source files got lost because stupid me made a mistake when setting up my backup process. Anyway, I *know* there's a solution. ;-)

The JSON I want to serialize comes from a web server sending data in the following form:

```json
{
    "version": "1.1",
    "error": {
        "name": "bla",
        "code": 1234,
        "message": "oops"
    },
    "result": ???
}
```

Either `error` or `result` is always `null` depending on whether my request could be processed. `result` can be anything from `boolean` to a really complex class.

My Java code structure looks like this:

```java
public class Response<T> {

    private String version;
    private T result;
    private Error error;

    public Response() {
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return error != null;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

public class Error {

    private String name;
    private int code;
    private String message;

    public Error() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

When I try to deserialize a `Response<Boolean>` or even a `Response<ArrayList<String>>` everything works fine, although I was a bit confused because `Response<String[]>` didn't work. Even the `error` field is populated correctly. Anyway, there is one thing which is *absolutely* not working, it's `Response<Device>` where `Device` is a very simple class looking like this:

```java
public class Device {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String type;
}
```

And finally, here is my deserialization code:

```java
private <T> Response<T> sendCommand(/* ... */) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // preparing and sending request etc.

    String responseJson = "..."; // response JSON is valid (already verified)

    Type t = new TypeToken<Response<T>>() { }.getType();
    Response<T> result = gson.fromJson(responseJson, t);
    return result;
}

private void doSomething() {
    Response<Device> response = sendCommand("getSomeDevice");
}
```

I googled for the last three hours, but I couldn't find any solution. (Maybe it's a basic Java issue, I usually code in C#.) Can anyone help me?

***Edit:***

I forgot to mention that when I'm debugging my code, it seems GSON deserialized the `Device` JSON to an object of type `LinkedTreeMap`. Don't know what that means, but maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely here:

```
Type t = new TypeToken<Response<T>>() { }.getType();
```

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), `T` will not be resolved at runtime. It will need to be up to the caller to pass in a properly reifiable type token:

```
private <T> Response<T> sendCommand(/* ... */, TypeToken<Response<T>> type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // preparing and sending request etc.

    String responseJson = "..."; // response JSON is valid (already verified)

    Response<T> result = gson.fromJson(responseJson, type.getType());
    return result;
}

private void doSomething() {
    TypeToken<Response<T>> type = new TypeToken<Response<Device>>() { };
    Response<Device> response = sendCommand("getSomeDevice", type);
}
```

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s version of [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), things can be further abstracted:

```
private <T> Response<T> sendCommand(/* ... */, TypeToken<T> responseType) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // preparing and sending request etc.

    String responseJson = "..."; // response JSON is valid (already verified)

    Type type = new TypeToken<Response<T>>() { }
            .where(new TypeParameter<T>() { }, responseType)
            .getType();
    Response<T> result = gson.fromJson(responseJson, type);
    return result;
}

private void doSomething() {
    Response<Device> response =
            sendCommand("getSomeDevice", new TypeToken<Device>() { });
}
```

Comment: I used your second approach using the Guava libs - works like a charm. Thank you.